# Suppose we have $n$ points in a plane, not all on the same line. Then they are determining at least $n$ different lines.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

> Suppose we have $n$ points in a plane, not
> all on the same line. Then they are determining at least $n$
> different lines.

Suppose points $T_1,...,T_n$ determine $m$
lines
$$\ell_i(x,y) :\;\;a_ix+b_iy+c_i=0;\;\;\;1\leq i\leq m$$ and let $L_k$ be a set of all lines
$\textbf{not}$ through $T_k$ and let $$p_k(x,y) = \prod _{\ell_i\in
L_k}\ell_i(x,y)$$ Then, since no line contains all points, the
degree of $p_k\leq m-1$. Also we have $p_k(T_k) \neq 0$ and
$p_j(T_k) =0$ for all $j\ne k$ which means that all $n$
polynomials are independent over vector space
$\mathbb{R}_{m-1}[x,y]$ which has a dimension ${m+1\choose 2}$. So
$$n\leq {m+1\choose 2} \implies m\geq {\sqrt{8n+1}+1\over 2}$$
which is pretty weak bound.

Any idea how to improve this approach?

Edit: [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921758/motivation-intuition-behind-using-linear-algebra-behind-these-combinatorics-prob)

Comment: Are you interested in a general solution or on making this kind of approach work specifically?

Comment: This kind of solution only, please.

Comment: Can you make all the $p_k$ of the same degree by multiplying by some more factors (some $l_s$ get multiplicities)? That would make the dimension of the vector space go from $\sim m^2$ to $\sim m$.

Comment: @Mindlack the constant term in each factor means there will always be $\sim m^2$ terms.

Comment: Just wanted to add tgat the classical and very short proof of this fact (which is called De Bruijn-Erdos theorem, by the way, see here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(incidence_geometry)) is relying on induction and the Sylvester-Gallai theorem: if you have $n$ noncollinear points on the plane, then there is a line passing through exactly two of them. See here for more: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem

Comment: The answer you gave in a comment bof already posted and now deleted, since it does not help here. I'm famililar with the subject  and I'm interested in alternative aproach with polynomials. Thank you any way @richrow

Comment: (a) Are you sure that there exists a solution using polynomials? If so, how do you know?$\tag*{}$ (b) Would you be interested in a solution which does not use polynomials, but does use linear algebra?

Comment: I'm familiar with solution using LA, but not with polynomials and I don't know if it exists. @MikeEarnest